# Clearcontent in another sheet based on ActiveCell

Tags: excel, vba

I try to make a commandbutton that ClearContents certain cells based on the ActiveCell over multiple sheets.

E.g. I selected cell A1 then the commandbutton should:
-  clear the contents for the cells 1st (A2), 3rd (A4) and 5th (A6) next to A1. and the same principle for the other sheets but different cells.

So far I only managed to clear cells on the current sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Basically if I selected A1 in sheet1 and press the commandbutton it should execute the code above and the same code ,but with different coordinates, for sheet2 and 3 etc.

Comment: Let s say you select cell A1, you want to clear A2, A4 & A6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the cells on all sheets in the workbook you will need to loop through each sheet. The below will loop through each sheet and clear the contents of the `Offset` cells in your question in relation to the `Activecell`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim coords As Object
    Dim j, key

    Set coords = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With coords
        .Add key:="Sheet1", Item:=Array(1, 3, 6, 7, 8)
        '.Add Key:="Sheet2", Item:=Array(2, 3, 6, 7, 9)
        ' ... etc.
    End With

    For Each key In coords
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(key)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            With ws.Range(ActiveCell.Address)
                For Each j In coords.Item(key)
                    .Offset(0, j).ClearContents
                Next j
            End With
        End If
    Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: HI Tom thx for the reply, but I need the coordinated to be different for the other worksheets.

Comment: @M.W. Your initial question doesn't specify what those coordinates are. You will still need to do what I have answered with but detect which sheet for which coords to use

Comment: I've got 10 sheets in total. The code mentioned is applicable for the first sheet. the following 8 sheets need the contents cleared of coordinates: (0,1) (0,2) (0,4) and (0,5).

Comment: Have a look at my update. Should the cleared cells be relevant to the `ActiveCell` or are they always in the samre place?

Comment: Should be relevant to the ActiveCell

Comment: @M.W. My update will work then - add your co-ords for each sheet into the `coords` dictionary using the sheet name as the `Key` and an array of the co-ords to clear for the `Item`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Row As Long, Column As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Column = ActiveCell.Column
    Row = ActiveCell.Row

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws
            .Cells(Row + 1, Column).ClearContents
            .Cells(Row + 3, Column).ClearContents
            .Cells(Row + 5, Column).ClearContents
        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```